# Is there a way to get value of json object from a URL in PHP?

Tags: php

So i am trying to get values of json object from a url, when i hit that url on post man i get something like this

```
{
    "error": "0",
    "errorString": "",
    "reply": {
        "nonce": "5e415334832a8",
        "realm": "VMS"
    }
}
```

So, i am trying to write a php code that displays the value of nonce in the browser but it is not working
i have the following code

```
$getNonceUrl = "https://example.com/api/getNonce";
$getContect = file_get_contents($getNonceUrl);
$jsonNoce = json_decode($getContect, true);
$dd = $jsonNoce->reply[0]->nonce;
echo $dd;
```

I also did this

```
$ch = curl_init("https://example.com/api/getNonce");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $ch->reply[0]->nonce;
```

But it does not seem to work still.

Comment: `var_dump($data);` What do you get?

Comment: According to your json, `reply` contains a single object, not an array of objects, so the proper way would be `reply->nonce`. And you forgot to decode the response on your curl, though you're trying to access it on the wrong variable anyway ($ch vs $data)

Comment: @aynber when i ```var_dump($data)``` i get ```boolean false```

Comment: Also, passing `true` as a second argument to `json_decode()` decodes the json into _arrays_, not objects. Try: `$jsonNoce['reply']['nonce']` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Below your 2 code samples with suggested corrections.

Using `file_get_contents` : remove 2nd argument of json_decode

```
$getNonceUrl = "https://example.com/api/getNonce";
$getContect = file_get_contents($getNonceUrl);
$jsonNoce = json_decode($getContect); // note removal of 2nd parameter
$dd = $jsonNoce->reply[0]->nonce;
echo $dd;
```

Using `curl` : you forgot to parse curl output with json_decode

```
$ch = curl_init("https://example.com/api/getNonce");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = json_decode($data); // added this line, because curl doesn't decode json automatically
echo $ch->reply[0]->nonce;
```